Political Compass Graph using Matplotlib
I have a lot of political coordinates data that I want to graph.
This is as far as I've gotten:

Ideally it would look as close to the actual compass as possible:

Here's the code:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xs = x_values
ys = y_values

plt.scatter(xs, ys)
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis([-11,11,-11,11]) 
plt.axhline(0)
plt.show()


IIUC, you want to plot the economic scale against the social one. If so, I would do the scatter this way. Of course, there might be a more straightforward approach but this one uses a single subplot (i.e, an axes) and starts by drawing the spectrum of the graph :
LL, UL = -10, 10 # limits
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for spine in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    if spine in ["left", "bottom"]:
        ax.spines[spine].set_position("zero")
    else:
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_ticks_position("none")

ax.tick_params(direction="inout", which="both")
ax.set(xlim=(LL, UL), ylim=(LL, UL), xticks=[], yticks=[])

for marker, pos in zip(
    [">", "^", "v", "<"],
    [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
):
    ax.plot(
        *pos, ls="", marker=marker,
        ms=10, color="k", clip_on=False,
        transform=(
            ax.get_yaxis_transform()
            if marker in [">", "<"]
            else ax.get_xaxis_transform()
        ),
    )

Then we add a text (as a label) of each axis :
font_kwgs = {"fontsize": 12, "fontname": "Lucida Sans"}
ax.text(0, UL+1, "Authoritarian", ha="center", **font_kwgs)
ax.text(0, LL-1, "Libertarian", ha="center", **font_kwgs)
ax.text(LL+1, 0, "Economic\n-Left", va="center", **font_kwgs)
ax.text(UL-4, 0, "Economic\n-Right", va="center", **font_kwgs)

Also, we fill each corner by a Polygon with the relevant color :
for offset, color in zip(
    [(LL, LL), (LL, 0), (0, 0), (0, LL)],
    ["#c8e4bc", "#f9baba", "#92d9f8", "#f5f5a7"],
):
    ax.add_patch(
        Polygon(
            [
                offset,
                (offset[0] + UL, offset[1]),
                (offset[0] + UL, offset[1] + UL),
                (offset[0], offset[1] + UL),
            ],
            facecolor=color,
        )
    )

And finally, we do plot the scales:
ax.scatter(xs, ys, c="w", ec="k", s=30)

Output (see full code) :

